# Class works without declaring variables?

Tags: php, oop

I'm learned php as functional and procedure language. Right now try to start learn objective-oriented and got an important question.

I have code:

```
class car {

    function set_car($model) {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    function check_model()
    {
        if($this->model == "Mercedes") echo "Good car";
    }

}

$mycar = new car;
$mycar->set_car("Mercedes");

echo $mycar->check_model();
```

Why it does work without declaration of $model?

`var $model;` in the begin?

Because in php works "auto-declaration" for any variables?
I'm stuck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every object in PHP can get members w/o declaring them:

```
$mycar = new car;
$mycar->model = "Mercedes";
echo $mycar->check_model(); # Good car
```

That's PHP's default behaviour. Those are public. See [manual](http://php.net/object).

Comment: Yes you can do this but it doesn't mean you *should*. Worth explaining a bit about that to the OP?

Comment: Can doesn't mean you shouldn't either, so what to explain? It's undefined (dynamic member), it's public - both has been mentioned in the answer. What especially are you concerned about?

Comment: I don't believe it's very good OO design unless it's absolutely necessary (and even then I'm struggling to think of a case when it's absolutely necessary). Given the OP is new to PHP (and I'm guessing new to OO as well) shouldn't we point out the dangers to him and that the default should be to declare all class properties.

Comment: Yeah, I think it should be mentioned. The class, for example, will spit out an undefined property notice if you call `check_model` before `set_car`, or before setting the property yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if it doesn't exist, PHP declares it on the fly for you.

It is more elegant to define it anyway, and when working with extends it's recommended, because you can get weird situations if your extends are gonna use the same varnames and also don't define it private, protected or public.

More info:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 3):

PHP class members can be created at any time. In this way it will be treated as **public** variable. To declare a **private variable** you need to declare it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But this way variables will be public. And declaration class variable as "var" is deprecated - use public, protected or private.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's because $model is an argument of the function set_car. Arguments are not exactly variables, but placeholders (references) to the variables or values that will be set when calling the function (or class method). E.g., $model takes the value "Mercedes" when calling set_car.

Comment: The question is not concerned to the function parameters. $model and $this->model are different variables. It could be $modelName or something else. 
Anyway it works

Answer (score 0):

I think this behavior can lead to errors.
Lets consider this code with one misprint

```
declare(strict_types=1);

class A
{
    public float $sum;
    public function calcSum(float $a, float $b): float
    {
        $this->sum = $a;
        $this->sums = $a + $b; //misprinted sums instead of sum
        return $this->sum;
    }
}

echo (new A())->calcSum(1, 1); //prints 1
```

Even I use PHP 7.4+ type hints and so one, neither compiler, nor IDE with code checkers can't find this typo.