# When to use @, and different ways to declare variables?

Tags: php, syntax, error-suppression

I'm learning object oriented php.
I've come across some code I don't fully understand.
This code is within a class.

1) code that uses @.
For example:

```
$this->image = @imagecreatefromgif($filename);
```

Can some one explain the uses of @.

2) 
Also it looks like the script is declaring variables in a way i'm not used to (the $var way).

For example:

```
$this->ext = $size['mime'];
```

$ext is not declared before this code is used, but it used after it. Does this create an $ext variable within the object?

Thanks guys!!

Comment: When to use [`@`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)? Never. Anything relying on `@` to silently ignore any errors and warnings is very likely badly designed.

Comment: Try not to ask unrelated questions in the same post, it confuses things. For the second question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042736/class-works-without-declaring-variables?rq=1

Comment: Barmar to the rescue again. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, Thanks. Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP? is gonna be a life saver.

Comment: Yours welcome ...There are plenty of more like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php but you need to do some re search to find them :)

Answer (score 1):

The `@` will suppress errors so that no errors will be shown for that expression.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: And please **read the warning** when studying that page in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

@ is php's error suppression operator you should never use it

You should handle error instead ignoring and advantage would be you will get long notice which is helpful to debug too

And worst case would be below as described in [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

> Currently the "@" error-control operator prefix will even disable error reporting for critical errors that will terminate script execution. Among other things, this means that if you use "@" to suppress errors from a certain function and either it isn't available or has been mistyped, the script will die right there with no indication as to why.

Comment: +1 for discouraging the usage of this operator.

Comment: @Bart Thankyou , @ operator is always makes problem if we dont know how to use properly and better not to use

Answer (score 0):

`@` Means "Suppress warning when calling this function".