# troubles with variables in PHP

Tags: java, php

I am new in PHP but from Java background. I am in a confusion with the following code:

```
class Student
{
    //public $name;
    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name=$name;
    }
    public function showname()
    {
        echo $this->name;
    }
}
```

On the above code if I comment the line `public $name;` it still works. However, in Java it is not supposed to work. I want to understand this behavior in PHP.

Comment: So what's your question? PHP and Java are different. You don't have to pre-define public class variables in PHP.

Comment: Yes, PHP does it for you (I think they are `public` by default).

Comment: By declaring `$this->name` you are adding the property of `name` to `$this`. If you declare it as public you can access it outside the class scope. If you declare it as private, when you try to access it from outside the class, PHP will throw error. So, I think it will work within the class scope even if you didn't declare as private, protected or public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP uses implicit declaration of properties. You can declare and assign a property from anywhere (even from outside the class).

```
<?php
$object1 = new User();
$object1->name = "Alice";
echo $object1->name;
class User {}
?>
```

would work fine and print "Alice"...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite simple, in your constructor every variable you are going to call with $this are going to be created in your Class, it is equivalent to declaring it in your class and then use it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a loosely typed language. Unlike in languages such as Java, you don't need to declare fields in a class in order to use them. By setting the name in the constructor, the field is created and set.

If you would remove the constructor or the field-setting in the constructor, the name would not exist when showname() is called.

Answer (score 0):

Thats PHP's default behaviour of auto declaration.

Your question is a dupliacte of 
[Stack overflow duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042736/class-works-without-declaring-variables)